# Offline Web Application: "Video could not be loaded" from AppCache in Chrome on Android 4.4.2 with video.js

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-applications, video.js, html5-appcache

i'm testing `Videoplayback` with `video.js` for a Web Application in offline mode.

In Desktop Chrome all works fine, the Video plays from `AppCache`, but in Android 4.4.2 (Nexus 4) there is an error:

```
VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported
```

Any suggestions please?

micha

Comment: did you figure this out?